# Sum if month is June and row text contains

Tags: excel, formula, spreadsheet

I'm hoping someone can help with a formula to input the value of Testing for June in  cell A20 (FOR EXAMPLE).

So first criteria is the month as Jun-21 and then the next is the word testing.

I need more than a basic sum function as it needs to include the total purely based on the month and the name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to lookup a value using both the row label and column label, using index/match is the formula to use. I assume you only have two different table, so this formula looks up the number in the first table, then looks up the value in the second table and adds them together.

`=INDEX(J3:P8,MATCH(B12,J3:J8,0),MATCH(B13,J3:P3,0))+INDEX(A3:G8,MATCH(B12,A3:A8,0),MATCH(B13,A3:G3,0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks heaps for that!

How about if it were two tables but only some items are in each. So say if testing was only in one table but passing is in both - I hope to be able to use the same sum for all so is there something I can add in to the formula so it knows to just include the one total if it can't see the name testing in the other table?

Would it be somehow incorporating a lookup instead?